# Is it possible to share filters between reports in Google Data Studio?

Tags: looker-studio

Google's Data Studio documentation makes some [vague references](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7326859?hl=en) to filtering functionality which does not appear to exist in the actual product. They say "Once you've added a filter to a report, you can use it in other components or even **other reports**."

However, there is no mention about how to do this. If I create a filter using the Filter Manager ( Resource > Manage filters ), the same filter does not magically become available in any of my other reports.

So is this a case of outdated documentation about a feature which has since been removed, or is there still some way to share filters between reports?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy a table or chart from an existing report  that has the filter you want into a new one and the filters go with it. It's the only way I've found of moving filters from one report to another